# How to get rid of std::cout quickly

Tags: c++, debugging, cout

I have inherited a large codebase where `std::cout` is very frequently used with the purpose of printing out debugging information. There is no real debug/log functionality in the code and since this will be a short lived task (bugfix) implementing debug/log functionality for now is out of the question.

It really bothers me the amount of text this program outputs, and at least till I have to work on it I would like to disable all the printouts on a temporary basis.

I see two solutions for now:

1. just comment them out... this is a lot of work because some of the `std::couts` span accross multiple line, so I would have to find them manually
2. replace all occurences of `std::cout` with a construct that has its own `operator <<` and simply swallows all the output

Do you have a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Why don't you replace all those console prints with a call to a log function/method? You can then enable/disable the print in a single location base on a various condition (like enable for debug only, or enable if the user selected this option, etc.).

Comment: *#ifdef* *DEBUG* `std::cout << ...` *#endif*

Comment: @MariusBancila There was no log functionality implemented in this project ... original highly paid contractors/consultants considered it unimportant/unsignificant

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter how it was originally. If you want to do something about it, then to the right thing.

Comment: @fritzone: that's not the point - if you change the `cout` statements to call some macro, you can have a no-op (do nothing) macro substitution initially, then later if you want to spend time on some enhanced logging (e.g. rolling fixed-sized files, history management, logging over TCP, system services etc) you can update the single macro that all logging goes through.

Comment: *"`std::cout` with a construct that has its own `operator <<` and simply swallows all the output"* if there's nothing but garbage (as far as you're concerned) on stdout, why not simply redirect it to /dev/null or OS-equivalent from the shell/caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect stdout programmatically with something like

```
FILE origSTDOUT = *stdout;
static FILE* nul = fopen( "NUL", "w" );
*stdout = *nul;
setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );
```

from the point you want to suppress output and restore with something like

```
*stdout = origSTDOUT;
```

to restore it.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. By wrapping it up in some global methods it works exactly the way as expected. And it has a very straightforward "clean" procedure too after I am done with my changes to the code.

Comment: @fritzone Something I didn't do was restore the buffer. You may want to do so, or not if it's for a quick and dirty hack.

Comment: It's just quick and dirty code, this will not go into production, just for local debugging without getting lost in all the other outputs. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

#### From within the application

If you want to do this from within the application itself, you can change the underlying [`std::streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) of `std::cout` so that any output effectively ends up somewhere else.

- [**cppreference.com** - `std::basic_ios::rdbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf)

---

<sup>**Example**</sup>

```
std::ostringstream buffer;
std::streambuf * cout_streambuf = std::cout.rdbuf (buffer.rdbuf ()); // (A)
```

```
std::cout << "hello world\n";                                        // (B)
```

```
std::cout.rdbuf (orig_cout_streambuf);                               // (C)
```

- *(A)* will set the underlying *streambuf* of `std::cout` to that of `buffer`, and return the old *streambuf* (effectively initializing *cout_streambuf* with this value).
- *(B)* write some data, effectively making it end up in our `std::ostreamstream`
- *(C)* reset the underlying *streambuf*, reverting to the previous state

> <sup>**Note**: *(B)* represents the part of your application where you'd like to have a *"redirected std::cout"*.</sup>

---

---

#### Using shell redirects

Instead of messing around with the application itself you could use the facilities provided by your shell, and simply redirect the output to *STDOUT* to `/dev/null` or equivalent (effectively discarding it)

<sub>***NIX**</sub>

```
./binary > /dev/null # send STDOUT to /dev/null
```

<sub>**WINDOWS**</sub>

```
./binary > NUL       # send STDOUT to NUL
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
std::cout.rdbuf(nulllptr);
```

Disables any output. Just add it to main.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect standard output to a null file. So, the outputs become invisible. In Unix systems, you can run your program like this: `program_name > /dev/null` on a console. For windows, you can try `program_name > nul`

Comment: Yup, indeed, that's a working solution, but what if **I** want to print out something that I want to see?